# Proving set's equalities through the membership table

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to wrap my head around sets and their laws in my free time. How is it possible to complete the following?

Prove that (*A* \ *C*) *∩* (*C* \ *B*) = *∅*

I understand that we have to follow certain laws in order to get *∅*. It would be great if someone could answer with steps and reasoning for applying such laws (e.g Associative Law).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the universe, and for $S \subseteq X$, let $S'$ denote the complement of $S$ in $X$.$\\[10pt]$
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&A\,{\setminus}\,C = A\cap C'\\[4pt]
&C\,{\setminus}\,B = C\cap B'\\[14pt]
\text{hence}\;\;&(A\,{\setminus}\,C) \cap (C\,{\setminus}\,B)\\[4pt]
&=\,(A\cap C')\cap (C\cap B')\\[4pt]
&=\,A\cap(C'\cap C)\cap B&&\text{[using generalized associativity of $\cap$]}\\[4pt]
&=\,A\cap {\large{\varnothing}} \cap B\\[4pt]
&=\,{\large{\varnothing}}
\end{align*}
The above proof stays at the set level.

But at the element level, the result is immediately obvious . . .

- Any element of $A\,{\setminus}\,C$ is not in $C$.$\\[4pt]$

  But any element of $C\,{\setminus}\,B\;$*must* be in $C$.

So there can't be an element in both $A\,{\setminus}\,C$ and $C\,{\setminus}\,B$.

Comment: Hey @quasi thank you for the answer! I totally understand this now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is need for De Morgan's Law. Proof by contradiction: suppose that it is not empty. Then by definition we can find an element $x$ in that intersection. Left part of $\cap $ says that $x$ is not in $C $, but the right part says that such an $x$ must be an element in $C$. Contradiction.

Comment: Hi @Pedro thank you for your answer! De Morgan’s Law was just an example, not a law that we would necessarily use for this problem. Contradicting makes logical sense actually, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in (A\setminus C)\cap (C\setminus B)$. Than $x\in A\setminus C$ so $x\notin C$. But $x\in (A\setminus C)\cap (C\setminus B)$ also implies that $x\in C\setminus B$ so $x\in C$. Now we have $x\notin C$ and $x\in C$. Contradiction.

Comment: Thank you @nightcap much appreciated!